# Method to get user details from LDAP/AD

Tags: c#

I'm using the code below to get various information about the logged in user and it works, but I want to turn it into a method where I can pass the attribute I want (`DisplayName`, `EmailAddress`, etc) and it returns that value for whoever is logged in. I couldn't figure out how to get this to work though.

```
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name))
    {
        if (user != null)
        {
            loggedInUserfullName = user.DisplayName;
            loggedInUserEmail = user.EmailAddress;
        }
    }
}
```

While the above works, I can't use any of those variables outside of the scope of the method, which isn't helpful.

I tried the method below to just get the `DisplayName` but got errors due to `FindByIdentity` expecting a string (I don't have a string with the user's name - that's what I'm trying to find out!)

```
public string getUserFullName(object user)
{
    user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ContextType.Domain, user);
    string loggedInUserDisplayName = user.DisplayName;
    return loggedInUserDisplayName ;
}

UserPrincipal loggedInUser = new UserPrincipal(ContextType.Domain); 
// line above throws cannot convert from 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType' to 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext'
getUserDetails(loggedInUser);
```

Is there a way to do this? Am I using the wrong library to achieve what I want?

This is a web application using windows authentication, if that makes any difference.

Thanks

Comment: using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement; do you have this

Comment: Yes, that is included in the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used the DirectoryServices.AccountManagement stuff in a long time, but I'll give this a shot.

This line in your code is throwing an exception:

```
UserPrincipal loggedInUser = new UserPrincipal(ContextType.Domain);
```

The exception is telling you that the constructor for UserPrincipal expects a System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext, but you're giving it a System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType. These lines in your working code are correct:

```
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name))
    {
```

I'm not sure I fully understand what your intention is, but if you are looking for a reusable way to get info about the logged in user, try something like this:

```
 public static class UserManager
{
    public static string GetDisplayName(string name)
    {
        using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain), name))
        {
            if (user != null)
            {
                return user.DisplayName;
            }

            throw new Exception("error");
        }
    }
}
```

You can call it by doing this:

```
var dn = UserManager.GetDisplayName(User.Identity.Name);
```

Obviously, you'll want to handle the error better. If I'm missing something, let me know and I'll try to update my answer.

Hope this helps!

**Edit**

To return an object containing multiple fields, you could do something like:

```
  public static UserInfo GetDisplayName(string name)
    {
        using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain), name))
        {
            if (user != null)
            {
                return new UserInfo
                {
                    FullName = user.DisplayName,
                    Email = user.EmailAddress,
                    GivenName = user.GivenName,
                    SamAccountName = user.SamAccountName,
                    Surname = user.Surname
                    //any other things you may need somewhere else
                };
            }

            throw new Exception("error");
        }          
    }
```

Here is the UserInfo class:

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public string GivenName { get; set; }

    public string SamAccountName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks good but id like a way to call UserManager.getattribute(attribute, name) or similar. Attribute being email, display name, or whichever active directory property I need. Is this possible?

Comment: use the debugger and you should be able to get at things like SamAccount name etc.. have you at least tried that @JayF1

Comment: @JayF1 If you want a way to dynamically return certain fields, I don't know that you can. What I might suggest is to create a class that holds the fields you'll likely need and return that object from the call. Then you can get whatever field you need in the calling method.

Comment: OK sounds like something I should just about be able to figure out :) thanks for your help